# Alphabetic Pattern Pyramid

Tags: beginner, c, ascii-art

I want to know if I can improve this program. Its goal is to print a pattern in a pyramid form, by first receiving a letter. The first row is always 'A', only. Then 'ABA', then 'ABCBA'. Increasing order, then decreasing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char alphabet[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char letter;

    printf("Enter an uppercase letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    letter -= 65;

    for (int row = 0; row <= letter; row++)
    {
        for (int spaces = letter; spaces > row; spaces--)
            printf(" ");

        for (char letter2 = 0; letter2 <= row; letter2++)
            printf("%c", alphabet[letter2]);

        for (char letter3 = 0 + row; --letter3 >= 0; )
            printf("%c", alphabet[letter3]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a static array of `chars` You could just use ASCII values from `0x41` to `0x5A`. If You still insist having a static array, please consider marking it as a `const`.

Leaving Your `int main()` without any return value --- sign of the bad taste, to say the least. Consider having some proper error codes or at least `return 0` on proper exit.

Your index of chars (`letter2`, `letter3`) can't be negative, so why would You use `int` instead of `uint_*` or `size_t`? Same applies to `row` and `spaces` variables.

In case of single char, `putchar()` is way faster then `printf("%c", character)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't return something because someone told me main() automatically returns 0. Is that actually true?

Comment: No, functions will not return anything unless you explicitly tell it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are requesting a 2d ASCII representational filling of an equilateral triangle using an incremental basic Latin ascended alphabetical array.

```
Array("a","b","c"...)
```

First we need to determine the parameters of the 'pyramid'
I will use 25 x 13.
I will also assume you want to draw down from the top.

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][A][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][R][S][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][R][S][T][U][ ][ ]
[ ][A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][R][S][T][U][V][W][ ]
[A][B][C][D][E][F][G][H][I][J][K][L][M][N][O][P][Q][R][S][T][U][V][W][X][Y]
```

Notice the `[ ]` these will need to be empty spaces for design purposes.

```
int main(void){
     unsigned short int dimensions[2] = [25, 13];
     unsigned short int n_characters = 1;
     for(unsigned short int row=0; row <= dimensions[1]-1; row++){
           printf("%c", alpha_string(n_characters);
           n_characters += 2;
     }
     return 0;
}
char* alpha_string(unsigned short int n_characters, unsigned short int width){
     char label[26] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
     char ret[n_characters];
     for (unsigned short int i= 0; i<= width-n_characters; i++){
          ret[i] = " ";
     }
     for (unsigned short int i= 0; i<= n_characters; i++){
          ret[i] = label[i];
     }
     return ret;
}
```

Consider this pseudo code, i free handed this without error checks.